# Connecting to an Azure Subscription in Azure China using an application created in Azure General region gives "AADSTS70001" error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a native application in an Azure AD in Azure General region. The application has been granted appropriate permissions (Sign in on user's behalf, execute Service Management API requests etc.). Using this application, I am able to connect to any Azure Subscription in Azure General region using this application.

However when I try to connect to an Azure Subscription in Azure China, after successful login, I am getting the following error:

> AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '01234567-890a-bcde-ffff-fcc63fc150ea' was not
>   found in the directory 'xxx.yyy.onmschina.cn'.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to connect to an Azure Subscription in Azure China (or for that matter to any Azure Subscription in Azure Sovereign Cloud like Germany etc.) using an application created in Azure General region?
- Or do I need to create a separate application for each Azure Sovereign region in an Azure AD in that region?
- If I indeed need to create a separate application (i.e. answer is yes to above question), is it possible to create an Azure AD tenant in these Sovereign regions without having an Azure Subscription there?

I believe the answer to the last question is yes considering Azure AD and Azure Subscription are two different things, yet I would very much like to get a confirmation on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

it is NOT possible to connect Azure "General" with any sovereign clouds - these are Azure US Government, Azure China, Azure Germany. All these clouds are completely separate deployments with their own Azure AD. You cannot use B2B inter clouds, you cannot use your multi-tenant applications across clouds.

For that case you have to have a subscription in every cloud you would like to support and separate application registration, and separate instructions for your users. Check for example [how Azure CLI is handling this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/manage-clouds-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest). You are always only connected to one cloud with cloud's specific account.

In Azure Germany you can create an Azure AD tenant - just [create a free trial subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-de-0044p/) and you will also get a tenant. For China and US Gov will be hard - they both have very strict requirements who can create subscriptions there.

Comment: Thanks Anton for clarifying!